# Changing the position of right click menu items

Tags: amd-radeon, context-menu, shell-extensions

I would very much like to reposition the AMD Radeon Settings option to be lower in the list. Is this even possible?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Try one of the context menu editors listed in [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/886999/337631)